# Why is my style not being applied to my range (Aspose Cells)?

Tags: excel, aspose, named-ranges, aspose-cells

I am creating a range, giving it a value, and styling it up like so:

```
private string fontForSheets = "Calibri";

Range unitNameRange = locationWorksheet.Cells.CreateRange("A1", "D1");

unitNameRange.PutValue(_unit, false, true); // val, isConverted, SetStyle. Don't know if these bools are right...
CellsFactory cf = new CellsFactory();
Style style = cf.CreateStyle();
style.HorizontalAlignment = TextAlignmentType.Left;
style.Font.Name = fontForSheets;
style.Font.IsBold = true;
style.Font.Size = 14;
unitNameRange.SetStyle(style);
```

But the style is not "taking" - the value is a simple, generic, bit of text; it is Arial 10, no bolding. How can I get the style to adhere to the range?

Is either the second or third, or both, wrong? I was guessing when setting isConverted to false and SetStyle to true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [check the reply related to this issue](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/818978/819013/showthread.aspx#819013) at the following Aspose.Cells forum.

**Note:** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: Can I reuse the Style and CellsFactory, instantiating them only once, or do I need to create a new Style and CellsFactory type for each cell?

Comment: Yes, you can reuse Style object. Just create it once and reuse it as per your needs.